# Awk Command not working as it should, output is wrong, sed command?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I tried this little script on my dataset and for some reason I am not getting the desired output? can someone have a look ? Maybe you can figure it out? Also if you could offer a SED command solution.

Script

```
awk -v RS= -F '<connection name="|<hostPort>' '
{
sub(/".*/, "", $2)
split($3, tokens, /[:<]/)
printf "%-6s %s %s\n", $2, tokens[1], tokens[2]
}
'
```

input

```
<hostPort>srv1:33333</hostPort>
<hostPort>srv2:33333</hostPort>
<connection name="boing_ny__Primary__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv1:33333</hostPort>
<connection name="boing_ny__Backup__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv2:33333</hostPort>
<connection name="boy_ny__Primary__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv1:6666</hostPort>
<connection name="boy_ny__Backup__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv2:6666</hostPort>
<connection name="song_ny__Primary__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv1:55555</hostPort>
<connection name="song_ny__Backup__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv2:55555</hostPort>
<connection name="bob_ny__Primary__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv3:33333</hostPort>
<connection name="bob_ny__Backup__" transport="tcp">
<hostPort>srv4:33333</hostPort>
<hostPort>srv1:4444</hostPort>
<hostPort>srv2:4444</hostPort>
<hostPort>srv1:4444</hostPort>
```

Current output

```
srv1:33333</hostPort>
srv2 33333
```

desired output

```
boing_ny__Primary__  srv1 33333
boing_ny__Backup__   srv2 33333
boy_ny__Primary__     srv1 6666
boy_ny__Backup__   srv2 6666
song_ny__Primary__ srv1 55555
song_ny__Backup__ srv2 55555
bob_ny__Primary__ srv3 33333
bob_ny__Backup__ srv4 33333
```

Comment: Use a XML parser not awk/sed

Comment: .up to you to test/use/throw   `awk -v RS='</hostPort>' '{$1=$1;match($0,/connection name="([^"]+).*<hostPort>(.*)/,a);gsub(/:/," ",a[2]);} length(a[1]){print a[1],a[2]}'`

Comment: Please describe in prose the purpose of your little script. That will help readers understand the code (or the error in it) and might help yourself finding the problem. Use all angles to understand your own code and its misbehaviour. It is similar to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
awk '/connection/{match($0,/"[^"]*/);VAL=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);next} /hostPort/ && VAL{match($0,/>.*</);print VAL FS substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'   Input_file
```

Will add explanation shortly.

**EDIT2:** Following is the explanation for same.

```
awk '/connection/{                                                    #### Looking for a line which has string connection in it.
                        match($0,/"[^"]*/);                           #### Using match function here to match a regex where it starts from " and looks for first occurrence of ".
                        VAL=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);            #### Now creating a variable named VAL whose value is substring of RSTART and LENGTH, where RLENGTH and RSTART are the default keywords of awk and they will be SET when a REGEX match is found. RSTART will give the index of starting point of match and RLENGTH will give the length of that regex match.
                        next                                          #### Using next keyword to skip all further statements.                               
                 }
    /hostPort/ && VAL{                                                #### Checking here 2 conditions, it checks for a line which has hostport string and value of variable VAL is NOT NULL, if these conditions are TRUE then perform following actions.
                        match($0,/>.*</);                             #### using match function of awk to get the srv values so putting here regex so match from >.*< get everything between > to <.
                        print VAL FS substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)    #### printing value of VAL(which got created in previous condition) then printing the substring of RSTART and RLENGTH values here.
                     }
    '  Input_file                                                     #### Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: Please use newlines to improve readability without much scrolling. If the only difference between two versions is the commenting, then why not delete the first (and second) version?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Reason they have been separated because commented version will not be executed, it is only for the understanding purposes, usually I put this while giving answers this time forgot to mention the same.

Comment: Ah. I was unaware of awk having no comment feature. That is of course a good reason. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 If i am not wrong, if the code breaks correctly , comments can be also part of the reall running code. You could keep just the version 2 (comment explained) code.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: Apostrophe in comments was the culprit, so I have removed it now and code with comments also running successfully for me. Also removed the previous without comments command now.

Comment: Yeap, apostrophe breaks the code , since awk is confused. Good job!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou awk is absolutely not confused by apostrophes anywhere. Put the script including apostrophes in a file named script and execute it as `awk -f script` to see that that is true. The issue is that you cannot use an apostrophe within an apostrophe-delimited script because **the shell** won't allow it since the shell sees an apostrophe within a script as the exit point from that script. That has nothing to do with awk or sed or any other script being called from the shell - it is a shell feature.

Comment: @Yunnosch you can have comments in awk scripts. They start with `#` and go to the end of the line, just like in shell scripts.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 while I'm all for use of white space of course, your massive indentation actually makes your code harder to read. Maybe try just bumping in 4 or so blanks per indentation level rather than 30 blanks or whatever that is you're using? And flying in the face of conventional wisdom and insisting on using all upper case variable names WILL bite you some day when your user-defined variable name clashes with a builtin variable name.

Comment: @Ed: Thank you for your suggestions, I will really try hard NOT to put capital letters variables(I remember you have told me 2 or 3 times). Also for indentation part, I have written long scripts, so it became habit to indent them in this manner, will try to work on it too.

Answer (score 1):

As comments refer the right way to do the job is to use an appropriate parser.

As for experimenting, this GNU awk seems to do the job with your input data provided, but can not guarantee a robust solution since XML data can vary in your files.

```
awk '/connection name=/{a=$0;getline; \
print gensub(/(.*connection name=["])(.[^"]*)(["].*)/,"\\2","g",a), \
gensub(/(<.*>)(.[^:]*)([:])(.[^<]*)(<[/].*>)/,"\\2 \\4","g",$0)}' file1

#Output:
boing_ny__Primary__ srv1 33333
boing_ny__Backup__ srv2 33333
boy_ny__Primary__ srv1 6666
boy_ny__Backup__ srv2 6666
song_ny__Primary__ srv1 55555
song_ny__Backup__ srv2 55555
bob_ny__Primary__ srv3 33333
bob_ny__Backup__ srv4 33333
```

How this works:
When we find a record containing `/connection name=/` we store this record `$0` to a variable `a`, we get next line with `getline`, and then we use and print two sed like substitutions using `gensub`:

```
gensub(/(.*connection name=["])(.[^"]*)(["].*)/,"\\2","g",a)
#all chars up to first " --|       |      |       |    |  |
#after " and up to the next "------|      |       |    |  |
#after last " up to the end of $0 --------|       |    |  |
#replace with group 2 ----------------------------|    |  |
#global replacement------------------------------------|  |
#target = a = previous record-----------------------------|

#With a = <connection name="boing_ny__Primary__" transport="tcp">
#Above gensub will return group2 = boing_ny__Primary__


gensub              (/(<.*>)(.[^:]*)([:])(.[^<]*)(<[/].*>)/,"\\2 \\4","g",$0)
#all chars between < >--|       |     |     |        |          |      |  |
#all chars up to : -------------|     |     |        |          |      |  |
#literal : ---------------------------|     |        |          |      |  |
#the part after : and before < -------------|        |          |      |  |
#the last < > part ----------------------------------|          |      |  |
#use group 2 and 4 ---------------------------------------------|      |  |
#global replacement ---------------------------------------------------|  |
#target = $0 current record ----------------------------------------------|

#With $0 = <hostPort>srv2:33333</hostPort>
#Above gensub will return group 2 = srv2 and group 4 = 33333 --> srv2 33333
```

The general awk gensub synthax is `gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])` and the substituted part is returned/applied on gensub function - [see man page of gensub.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Heavily updated - wrong concept before - now should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

robust:
`cat input | awk -F'\"|>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}' | sed -z 's/_\n/_ /g' | grep -v ^srv | tr ":" " "`

Comment: plz let me know

Comment: awk, sed or grep, they are able to read the file by themselves, you have done UUOC(Useless use of cat) here. As a initial point I have told that, we could definitely do it with single awk or sed too.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I would suggest a small part of your code if you allow me:
      `VAL2=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);`
       `sub(/:/, " ", VAL2)`
       `print VAL FS VAL2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[":<>]' '/hostPort/{if (n!="") print n, $3, $4; n=""; next} {n=$3}' file
boing_ny__Primary__ srv1 33333
boing_ny__Backup__ srv2 33333
boy_ny__Primary__ srv1 6666
boy_ny__Backup__ srv2 6666
song_ny__Primary__ srv1 55555
song_ny__Backup__ srv2 55555
bob_ny__Primary__ srv3 33333
bob_ny__Backup__ srv4 33333
```